# How can I pass input parameters into a hyperlink?

Tags: parameters, apexinputfield

I'm a beginner in Visualforce pages & Apex. I'd like to use the inputfield value that is entered by user in order to pass it through an URL as a parameter.
The URL would look like :

```
"http://<URL>?&confirmation_date=<Batch_date_confirmation__c>"
```

Anyone can assist me on that?

```
<apex:page standardController="Winners_payment_batch__c">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Warning!">
  {!$User.FirstName}, you're about to proceed to the payment of batch : {!Winners_payment_batch__c.Name}, of which total to be paid is : <h1>{!Winners_payment_batch__c.Total_prize_to_be_paid__c}</h1><p/>
  Please confirm the Batch date : <p/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Winners_payment_batch__c.Batch_date_confirmation__c}"/><p/>
  <apex:commandButton action="https://en.eyeka.com" value="Confirm payment"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach - no controller code required

- Use apex:actionSupport to transmit change in batchDate to controller and refresh the commandButton
- Use `URLFOR` and especially the third argument to construct parameters to the URL. Note that you use the `{!` only once, SFDC VF is clever enough to bind the value after the `=` of `Winners_payment_batch__c.Batch_date_confirmation__c` to the current value known to the controller.

  ```
  <apex:inputField value="{!Winners_payment_batch__c.Batch_date_confirmation__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="btn"/>
  </apex:inputField>

  <apex:commandButton id="btn" 
    action="{!URLFOR('https://en.eyeka.com',null,[confirmation_date=Winners_payment_batch__c.Batch_date_confirmation__c])}" 
    value="Confirm payment"/>
  ```